# Site Analytics also for non Site Owners possible?

Tags: 2013, security, reports, analytics

Is it possible to make the Popularity and Search Reports accessible to contributors and not only owners?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to run your IIS logs through a web analytics software product.  This provides the reports and overcomes the limitations of SharePoint's built-in reporting, which is weak anyway.

Comment: That is true, I will upvote it, but it is not an answer for my question.